# custom validation (Existing email)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I wanted to use express-validator to check if the email exists
here is my code:

```
router.post('/', [
  check('username', 'Min 5 chars, Max 20').isLength({ min: 5, max: 20 }),
  check('email').custom(async value => {
      const db = require('../db');
return await db.query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=?', [value], function (err, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
              return false;
        } else { return true; }
      })
  }).withMessage('Email already exists'),
], function(req, res, next) {

  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
```

....

The problem with async/await that the validation didnt execute at all even if the return is true or false. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using bad `async/await` commands. And to be honest, you don't need them here.

```
router.post('/', [
  check('username', 'Min 5 chars, Max 20').isLength({ min: 5, max: 20 }),
  check('email').custom(value => {
      const db = require('../db');
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          db.query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=?', [value], function (err, results, fields) {
             if (err)
                reject(err)
             if (results.length>0)
                reject(new Error('Email Already exists'))
             resolve()
          })
       })

  }),
], function(req, res, next) {

  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
```

Comment: it's not works! in console says /home/user/test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: Email Already exists
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/user/test/routes/register.js:36:16)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/user/test/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:957:21)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/user/test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
.....